# ¿Como imprimir en un texto mediante js?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este codigo en html que es básicamente 3 cajas de texos y 4 botones con las operaciones matemáticas:

```
<body>
<h2>Esta es una practica de JavaScript</h2>  
<p>¿Que operacion matematica, Quieres realizar?</p> 
<p>Digijite el primer numero</p>
<input type="text" name="numero1" id="numerito1">
<br>
<br>
<p>Digijite el segundo numero</p>
<input type="text" name="numero2" id="numerito2">
<br>
<br> 
<input type="button" value="Suma" id="sumita">
<input type="button" value="Resta" id="restita">
<input type="button" value="Multiplicacion" id="multiplicacioncita">
<input type="button" value="Division" id="divisioncita">
<br>
<br>
<p>El resultado es:</p>
<input type="text" name="numero_final" id="numerito_final">
<script src="operaciones.js">  </script>
```

En js tengo ya la funciones de cada operación y funcionan cuando oprimo el boton me lanza un alert diciendo el resultado pero quiero que aparezca en la caja de texto donde dice el resultado es:

```
var numero1_js = document.getElementById("numerito1");
var numero2_js = document.getElementById("numerito2");
var numero3_js = document.getElementById("numerito_final");
var sumita_js = document.getElementById("sumita");
var restita_js = document.getElementById("restita");
var multiplicacioncita_js = document.getElementById("multiplicacioncita");
var division_js = document.getElementById("divisioncita");

sumita_js.addEventListener("click", sumar,);
restita_js.addEventListener("click", resta,);
multiplicacioncita_js.addEventListener("click", multiplicacion,);
division_js.addEventListener("click", division,);

function sumar(){
 var n1 = parseInt(numero1_js.value);
 var n2 = parseInt(numero2_js.value);
 var numero3_js = n1 + n2;
 alert("El resultado es " + numero3_js);
}
function resta(){
    var n1 = parseInt(numero1_js.value);
    var n2 = parseInt(numero2_js.value);
    var numero3_js = n1 - n2;
    alert("El resultado es " + numero3_js);
   }

   function multiplicacion(){
    var n1 = parseInt(numero1_js.value);
    var n2 = parseInt(numero2_js.value);
    var numero3_js = n1 * n2;
    alert("El resultado es " + numero3_js);
   }

   function division(){
    var n1 = parseInt(numero1_js.value);
    var n2 = parseInt(numero2_js.value);
    var numero3_js = n1 /n2;
    alert("El resultado es " + numero3_js);
   }
```

Comment: Que tal, bueno, en el addEventListener como segundo parámetro usas las funciones que has hecho, pero estan mal escritas... seria: sumar(), y tienes que sacar las comas que están al final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder pasar el valor de cualquiera de las funciones al input, debes usar el objeto `value`

> Te dejo el ejemplo de como debe verse tu función `suma` pero es la
>   misma lógica a aplicar para todas las demás que tienes en tu script

**Función suma**

```
sumita_js.addEventListener("click", function(){
   var n1 = numero1_js.value
   var n2 = numero2_js.value
   var numero3_js = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2)
   document.getElementById("numerito_final").value = numero3_js
})
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

- Pasé dentro del listener como segundo argumento una función anónima que procese la suma
- Meto dentro del método `parseInt()` los valores que se van a sumar
- Obtengo por medio de su id al input que le quiero pasar el valor, de este modo `document.getElementById("id")`
- Para poder asignar el valor de la suma al input, al final hago uso de `.value=numero3_js`

Simplemente replica esto por cada una de tus operaciones que deseas realizar

**TU EJERCICIO CON LAS OBSERVACIONES HECHAS**

```html
    <h2>Esta es una practica de JavaScript</h2>  
    <p>¿Que operacion matematica, Quieres realizar?</p> 
    <p>Digijite el primer numero</p>
    <input type="text" name="numero1" id="numerito1">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Digijite el segundo numero</p>
    <input type="text" name="numero2" id="numerito2">
    <br>
    <br> 
    <input type="button" value="Suma" id="sumita">
    <input type="button" value="Resta" id="restita">
    <input type="button" value="Multiplicacion" id="multiplicacioncita">
    <input type="button" value="Division" id="divisioncita">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>El resultado es:</p>
    <input type="text" name="numero_final" id="numerito_final">
    <script>
      var numero1_js = document.getElementById("numerito1");
    var numero2_js = document.getElementById("numerito2");
    var numero3_js = document.getElementById("numerito_final");
    var sumita_js = document.getElementById("sumita");
    var restita_js = document.getElementById("restita");
    var multiplicacioncita_js = document.getElementById("multiplicacioncita");
    var division_js = document.getElementById("divisioncita");
    
    sumita_js.addEventListener("click", function(){
       var n1 = numero1_js.value
       var n2 = numero2_js.value
       var numero3_js = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2)
       document.getElementById("numerito_final").value = numero3_js
    })
      
    restita_js.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var n1 = numero1_js.value
        var n2 = numero2_js.value
        var numero3_js = parseInt(n1) - parseInt(n2)
        document.getElementById("numerito_final").value = numero3_js
    })
    
    
    multiplicacioncita_js.addEventListener("click", function(){
         var n1 = numero1_js.value
         var n2 = numero2_js.value
         var numero3_js = parseInt(n1) * parseInt(n2)
         document.getElementById("numerito_final").value = numero3_js
    })
    
    division_js.addEventListener("click", function(){
         var n1 = numero1_js.value
         var n2 = numero2_js.value
         var numero3_js = parseInt(n1) / parseInt(n2)
         document.getElementById("numerito_final").value = numero3_js
    })
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Propongo esta solución, aunque creo que se podría realizar de una manera más limpia este ejercicio.

```js
            // Te recomiendo que definás tus variables de esta manera numeroUnoJs
            // Si revisás documentación o métodos en javascript es minúsula mayúscula al igual que las funciones 
            var numero1_js = document.getElementById('numerito1');
            var numero2_js = document.getElementById('numerito2');
            var numero3_js = document.getElementById('numerito_final');
            var sumita_js = document.getElementById('sumita');
            var restita_js = document.getElementById('restita');
            var multiplicacioncita_js = document.getElementById('multiplicacioncita');
            var division_js = document.getElementById('divisioncita');
    
            sumita_js.addEventListener('click', sumar);
            restita_js.addEventListener('click', resta);
            multiplicacioncita_js.addEventListener('click', multiplicacion);
            division_js.addEventListener('click', division);
            function sumar() {
                // si es que necesitaras definir cada variable en las funciones utiliza let (local), var es global
                let n1 = parseInt(numero1_js.value);
                let n2 = parseInt(numero2_js.value);
                let numero3_js = 0
                numero3_js = n1 + n2;
                // Para definirlo en tu elmento numero_final es sencillo haz lo mismo que hiciste para obtener
                document.getElementById('numerito_final').value = numero3_js;
                //alert('El resultado es " + numero3_js);
            }
            function resta() {
                let n1 = parseInt(numero1_js.value);
                let n2 = parseInt(numero2_js.value);
                let numero3_js = 0
                numero3_js = n1 - n2;
                document.getElementById('numerito_final').value = numero3_js;
                //alert('El resultado es " + numero3_js);
            }
    
            function multiplicacion() {
                let n1 = parseInt(numero1_js.value);
                let n2 = parseInt(numero2_js.value);
                let numero3_js = 0
                numero3_js = n1 * n2;
                document.getElementById('numerito_final').value = numero3_js;
                //alert('El resultado es " + numero3_js);
            }
    
            function division() {
                let n1 = parseInt(numero1_js.value);
                let n2 = parseInt(numero2_js.value);
                let numero3_js = 0
                numero3_js = n1 / n2;
                document.getElementById('numerito_final').value = numero3_js;
                //alert('El resultado es " + numero3_js);
            }
```

```html
    <body>
        <h2>Esta es una practica de JavaScript</h2>
        <p>¿Que operacion matematica, Quieres realizar?</p>
        <p>Digijite el primer numero</p>
        <input type="text" name="numero1" id="numerito1">
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Digijite el segundo numero</p>
        <input type="text" name="numero2" id="numerito2">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Suma" id="sumita">
        <input type="button" value="Resta" id="restita">
        <input type="button" value="Multiplicacion" id="multiplicacioncita">
        <input type="button" value="Division" id="divisioncita">
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>El resultado es:</p>
        <input type="text" name="numero_final" id="numerito_final">
```